# Titanium Backup from Nandroid using pc

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, titanium-backup, nandroid

I know you can create a Titanium Backup from a Nandroid Backup using the Titanium Backup PRO app.

But is there a possibility to create a Titanium Backup from a Nandroid without having a phone, i.e. using a pc (preferably Linux, Windows is ok too)?

Answer (score 3):

*Titanium Backup* is able to read from Nandroid backups, so you can use it to restore parts from them -- and then use *Titanium Backup* again to backup those restored parts. However, as there's no *Titanium Backup* for PC, this has to be done on an Android device.

If your goal however is to separate some apps from a Nandroid backup, there are other ways to achieve this: Nandroid copies the entire partition (see: [nandroid tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/nandroid/info)). So you could mount the images (on Linux, this should be no problem with the EXT file systems at least -- see e.g. [Restore only part of nandroid image](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/7851/16575)), or unpack them (for YAFFS partitions e.g. using `unyaffs` -- see [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/28594/16575)).

For completeness: there are also ADB-style backups (which again *Titanium Backup* is able to access). For these, you might want to take a look at e.g. [Android Backup Extractor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/) and [Android Backup Splitter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/adb-split/), and also [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/42224/16575) on how to convert an ADB backup into a tar file to investigate, using the Perl AdbBackupRoutines from [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27840175#post27840175).